# Vue props undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to Vue and I am trying to get parent's component data with props from a child component but got an undefined error when I do console.log().

Parent:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import PieChart from './components/PieChart'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      requires: [],
      tested: [],
      requires_php: [],
      errors: [],
      url: 'https://api.miruc.co/plugins.min.json'
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    axios.get(this.url)
    .then(response => {
      this.requires = response.data[0]
      this.tested = response.data[1]
      this.requires_php = response.data[2]
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
  },
  components: {
    'pie-chart': PieChart
  }
}
```

Child:

```
export default {
  extends: Pie,
  props: ['req'],
  mounted: function () {
    console.log(this.req)
    /*  */
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what mistake I am doing?

Comment: I would guess that the http get is still running by the time your console.log is reached.

Comment: @RichardMatsen I tried with `setTimeout(function () { alert(this.req) }, 10000)` but I still get the same error. Even the Vue extenstion on Chrome says it's undefined.

Comment: You can find out for sure by putting another console.log in the `.then(response => {` method and see what order they appear in.

Comment: I got undefined there... it's weird, Vue extension says it stores an object.

Comment: Ok, I didn't expect that. 'Vue extension' - what's that?

Comment: Vue.js devtools https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd

Comment: The url you show above works - is that the real one, or just an example?

Comment: It is the real one... How does it work? I am using vue-cli and webpack template.

Comment: So, to clarify - `response` is empty in the `then` function? I was wondering about the `.data' property. Maybe the response is just equal to the array of objects. So, you're in Auckland?

Comment: Nope, response returns an object, but the `this.requires` is undefined in the .then function. But I can actually get the values with something like `<div v-for="rq in requires">{{ rq }}</div>`. Not sure why.

Comment: Show us how you pass the props

Comment: I'll set up a CodePen and see what's what.

Comment: This'll be it, try - `.then( function(response) { `

Comment: No, spoke too soon. Works with fat arrow too.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce. This is my [CodePen ](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/rYNqQa)

Comment: I've added a watch to the child in codepen, you can see the change when axios.get resolves, but the console.log in mounted reports the initial (weird) value. So, back to my first comment - child mounted console.log is firing before the fetch is complete.

Comment: Omg, it is working... Thanks for your work, I don't know why it doesn't work on my vue-cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass props to a child-component within the parents template, e.g:

```
<template>
//...
    <pie-chart :req="requires"></pie-chart>
//...
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you did with your template codes. But see what happens when you change your Parent's code like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import PieChart from './components/PieChart'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      requires: [],
      tested: [],
      requires_php: [],
      errors: [],
      url: 'https://api.miruc.co/plugins.min.json'
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    axios.get(this.url)
    .then(response => {
      Vue.set(this, 'requires', response.data[0])
      Vue.set(this, 'tested', response.data[1])
      Vue.set(this, 'requires_php', response.data[2])
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
  },
  components: {
    'pie-chart': PieChart
  }
}
```

One thing to remember: whenever you set an array or object elements always use `Vue.set`. It assures reactivity for the inner elements.